# Ajax custom in-line message in form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using ajax for many forms, the problem is that when I enter one of the forms the message that returns is shown in all the forms, there is a way to avoid this so that only the message is shown in the form sent and not in the others ?

Here is the input html adaptation:

```
 <!-- FORM 1-->
 <form name="name" action="form.php" method="POST" id="contact1">
 <li class="text-info">Name</li>
 <select name="age">
 <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
 <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="namevalue">
 </form>

    <div id="result1"></div>

<!-- FORM 2-->
<form name="likes" action="form.php" method="POST" id="contact2">
<ul>
<li class="text-info">Interests</li>

<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="play_soccer">Play Soccer</input>

<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="play_golf">Play Golf</input>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="gamevalue">
 </form>

<div id="result2"></div>
```

And the js for ajax is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    // Getting the form ID
    var formID = $(this).attr('id');
    var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'form.php',
      data: formDetails.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        // Inserting html into the result div
        $('#results1').html(data);
        $('#results2').html(data);


      },

    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

So in form.php when a form is submitted separately, every form send the message with a simple echo notifying that it was updated.

Any help its welcome, thanks

Comment: specify in php what message should be shown in what form, so that you have `data.result1`, `data.result2`,.. _OR_ add `data` only to the form that triggers the submit event (via `$(this).html`).

Comment: Some basic example to try the data.result1?

Comment: would be in your php , which you haven't shown yet. But basicly return a json_encoded array `["result1" => "what to show in form1", "result2" => "..."]`

Comment: so why are you setting multiple elements if you want it in one? Is the output div right outside of the form?

Comment: @epascarello is to not do many separate forms

Comment: Why are you using an `<li>` as a `<label>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If You don't change anything than you need just add below condition with success response

`if(formID=='contact1')
       $('#results1').html(data);
 else if(formID=='contact2')
       $('#results2').html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a data attribute

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const form = $(this);
  const outputElem = $(form.data("output"))
  outputElem.text(form.attr("id"))
  console.log(form.serialize())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="name" action="form.php" method="POST" id="contact1" data-output="#result1">
  <select name="age">
    <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
    <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="namevalue">
</form>
<div id="result1"></div>

<form name="name" action="form.php" method="POST" id="contact2" data-output="#result2">
  <select name="age">
    <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
    <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="namevalue">
</form>
<div id="result2"></div>
```